# Ios SKSpriteNode prevent negative x velocity

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, collision-detection, skspritenode

I'm making a game with SpriteKit that involves a hero bouncing on a surface in the positive x and y direction. The hero has this size:

```
CGSize heroSize = CGSizeMake(hero.size.width-140, hero.size.height-35);
hero.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:heroSize];
hero.physicsBody.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES;
```

and uses `applyImpulse` to bounce in the positive x/y direction:

```
[self.physicsBody applyImpulse:CGVectorMake(xvelocity, yvelocity)];
SKAction *rotation = [SKAction rotateByAngle: -2.0/M_PI duration:.5];
[self runAction: rotation];
```

The ground has a friction level of 0.4 and restitution of .5. Because the hero rotates when bouncing, he will sometimes bounce backwards and have a negative X velocity. I was wondering if there is any way to prevent an `SKSpriteNode` from moving in the -X direction.  Would a solution be to create a better size for the physics body of my `SKSpriteNode`? It seems like this could happen with any shape, but would be less likely with more circular objects. Any input is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: How about adding the hero to another node and apply the impuls to that node instead?

Comment: I thought of a workaround that I could use help with. I want to prevent the hero from moving past the left side of the visible screen. I want there to be an invisible wall on the left side of the screen that prevents the hero from moving past it if it starts to move in the - X direction. Right now, I have the camera centering itself on the hero  on the didSimulatePhysics method.

So, if the hero moves with negative X velocity then I stop centering the camera on the hero and create an invisible wall that is -self.view.frame.size.width/2 away from the hero. Does this sound good?

Comment: If it is -self.view.frame.size.width/2 from the hero, it might be out of screen if the hero is not properly centered.

Answer (score 1):

You can monitor your hero's velocity and limit negative x movement by using this:

```
if(hero.physicsBody.velocity.dx < 0) {
    hero.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, hero.physicsBody.velocity.dy);
}
```

Comment: Hm, okay. So make the hero jump in place if he strikes the ground in such a way that he should move in the negative x direction. I feel like this still won't look good if the hero is traveling at a large x velocity then it suddenly becomes 0. Perhaps i'll try taking the absolute value of the x-velocity if it is ever negative and set that to be the hero's velocity. Thanks for the reply

Comment: @JoshNussbaum - If your hero is traveling at a large x velocity he must obviously be going forward. In what circumstance would his velocity go from a big positive x to a negative x? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: This mostly happens in cases where his x velocity is small, however, it sometimes occurs when the hero comes down from a high angle and because his skphysicsbody is a rectangle, he will strike the ground in such a way that he gets pushed in the negative X direction.